# How to use JSON with Jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I'm working at an app which would make a POST ajax request to a PHP script on my server. The script would query the database and return a row of records, as an array. (One array for each row, containing elements such as id, title, etc). I then want to use `json_encode()` to encode this array, and pass it back to the javascript which will use it to display the records.

1) How can I return the JSON encoded string to the javascript?
2) How will the javascript loop through the rows and access their fields?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get JSON with jQuery, just use [jQuery.getJSON()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON). Alternatively, you can use any other AJAX tool and then just eval() the json to get a javascript object.

To loop through an array, I usually use [jQuery.each()](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each):

```
var recordList = yourMethodToGetRecordListWithAjax();

jQuery.each(recordList, function()
{
    alert(this.Name); // For example
});
```

Comment: There's a small typo in your answer, jquery.each should be $.each. Other than that it works good :)

Comment: Here's my code:   



$.getJSON("getData.php",data,myFunctionToLoopThroughResults);

Comment: $ is a shortcut for jQuery - I prefer to write jQuery for "static" things like each() and use $ for "non-static" things like queries as I believe it enhances readability.

Comment: But it's really up to you and your personal taste.

Comment: I tried using jquery but it gave me an error in firebug, so I dunno

Comment: it's jQuery, not jquery. It is case-sensitive.

Comment: careful with the first A in AJAX.  `async: false` would probably be a good idea within that ajax call

Answer (score 4):

1) in the php script:

```
$return["foo"]  = "bar";
$return["blah"] = "bleg";
print json_encode($return);
```

2) in the javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: URL,
  cache: false,
  data: values,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(json) {
    var foo = json.foo;
    if (json.blah == "bleg") {
      // do stuff 
    }
  } // end success function
}); // end ajax call
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the JSON encoded string to the JS by echoing it with a Content-Type of application/json.

See above answer for the rest.