# Pass multiple arrays to javascript via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays, json

To pass an array from PHP to javascript via ajax, I am going to use json_encode, and recieve it on the javascript end.
However, I will be returning multiple rows from my MySQL database, and need to return multiple JSON-formatted arrays. One way I thought of doing this was to string the JSON arrays together in php with some obscure character, such as a pipe character, and then separate them on the javascript end. But is there a more elegant way to do this?

Edit: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515684/how-to-use-json-with-jquery) explains what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 13):

Just send them as an JSON-encoded array of arrays.

```
<?php
$row=array('foo'=>'bar','baz'=>'quux');
echo json_encode(array($row,$row,$row,$row));
?>
```

Results in

```
[
 {"foo":"bar","baz":"quux"},
 {"foo":"bar","baz":"quux"},
 {"foo":"bar","baz":"quux"},
 {"foo":"bar","baz":"quux"}
]
```

This can then be processed exactly like an array on the client side.